# If statements without brackets

Tags: c, if-statement

I'm hoping to get some clarification on `if` and `if else` statements that do not have brackets and how to read them. I can read `if else`, and `else if` statements with brackets easily and they make sense to me but these have always confused me, here is a sample question.

```
if (x > 10)      
     if (x > 20)
          printf("YAY\n");    
else      printf("TEST\n");
```

Comment: this is highly language dependent. Please specify the language this code is in (I'd guess C, but could be otherwise).

Comment: Having said that, the general rule in most curly-brace languages is that a flow-control statement need not have bracketed scope if the contents of the statement is a single expression. In this case, it's leveraging the fact that `if(x<20) printf("YAY\n")` collapses into a single expression, so passes muster to be contained under `if(x<10)` without the need for braces.

Comment: an `else` always refer to the `if` conditioning the previous expression or block.

Comment: as a side note an personal view, i think actions should be taken against people who use ifs without brackets in languages that allow both behaviors.

Comment: @njzk2 Indeed. Apple [learned this the hard way](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/02/24/anatomy-of-a-goto-fail-apples-ssl-bug-explained-plus-an-unofficial-patch/). Unbracketed flow-control statements are usually outlawed by most style guides (sometimes with an exception for `if (condition) return` statements) because they are an endless source of bugs.

Answer (score 16):

If there are no brackets on an if/else, the first statement after the if will get executed.

If statement:

```
if (condition)
    printf("this line will get executed if condition is true");
printf("this line will always get executed");
```

If/else:

```
if (condition)
    printf("this line will get executed if condition is true");
else
    printf("this line will get executed if condition is false");
printf("this line will always get executed");
```

**Note:** Your code will break if there are multiple commands between an if and its matching else.

```
if (condition)
    printf("this line will get executed if condition is true");
    printf("this line will always get executed");
else
    printf("this else will break since there is no longer a matching if statement");
```

Answer (score 10):

Without the brackets, the `else` will relate to the `if` it's immediately after. So, to properly indent your example:

```
if (x > 10)      
     if (x > 20)
          printf("YAY\n"); 
     else // i.e., x > 10 but not x > 20
          printf("TEST\n");
```

Answer (score 3):

An if statement without brackets will only take into account the next expression after the if:

```
 if(foo > 5)
   foo = 10;
 bar = 5;
```

Here, foo will only be set to 10 if foo is bigger than 5 but bar will always be set to 5 because it's not inside the scope of the if statement, that would require brackets.

Comment: It actually doesn't have to be on a new line. It's the next *expression/statement* after it. `if (foo > 5) foo = 10;` would be perfectly valid as well.